# how to access obj from json in React?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

**Api Respose :-**

```
 [
      {
        "System Name": "Name1",
        "Primary Sensor": "WWWW",
        "Mean Wind Speed": "6.23 m/s",
        "Status": 1,
        "mws_number": 44,
        "DRR (%)": "100",
        "drr_number": 100
      },
      {
        "System Name": "Name 2",
        "Primary Sensor": "SSSS",
        "Mean Wind Speed": "4.2 m/s",
        "Status": 2,
        "mws_number": 6,
        "DRR (%)": "100",
        "drr_number": 100
      }
    ]
```

**My Code ->**

```
    class Home extends Component {
    state = {
          items:[],
            isLoading:false
            }
     componentDidMount() {
    // api
            fetch('http://api.url', {
              method: 'POST',
              body: 
               JSON.stringify({"Authentication":'token'})
             }).then(data => data.json() )
             .then(res =>{
            this.setState({isLoading:true,
            items:res,}
    )
          });
    }
    render() {
    return (
    <>
     {console.log(this.state.items[0])} // getting o/p - first obj of array
     {console.log(this.state.items[0].Status)} // getting Error undef Status
     {console.log(this.state.items.Status[0])} // same error undef status
    </>
)
export def ....
```

This is my complete piece of code... I can't add api url as it is not public api :(
I want to access this data inside of the array =>(Status, System Name, etc)
how can i fetch this !!

Comment: can you share your code snippet of your react component (or function) that is calling the api / console logging.

Comment: essentially we want to check that you are console logging after you have a response.  setState is an async call and so is fetch.  I understand you are able to console.log(this.state.items) but just want to see the component calling it

Comment: (2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {System Name: "Name1", Primary Sensor: "WWWW", Mean Wind Speed: "6.23 m/s", Status: 3, mws_number: 6.23, …}
1: {System Name: "Name2", Primary Sensor: "NNNN", Mean Wind Speed: "6.41 m/s", Status: 1, mws_number: 6.41, …}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: This is the respose I copy, as it is from the console so it might look disturbing but this is the response I am getting back, I don't know actually how to access these data inside of the object

Comment: i belive you are console loging the state just after when you change state with `setState`.setState will work only after the full function is completed. i mean after the render.so if you can access your response data in state only after the function completes

Comment: @ChitrangSharma, make sure you are not calling the console log right after the setState() call, since setState is asynchronous in the nature, you won't get the response immediately, you can use react dev tools to inspect if the state is getting set or not, when you set the state, you'll see the updated values in the tools, no need to use console log here.

Comment: Also, what API are you using here, since you are facing the issue in it too, you should post the full details of it, cause we won't be able help if you don't provide any api endpoint

Comment: no I am not logging data after setState (Undefined if I do ) ,I am console logging it in the return statement and it is giving the above mentioned result

Comment: Can you post your whole code, so that we can see where it is getting logged, also try to inspect the component via react dev tools, you'll be able to see if the state is updated or not. Also where are you calling this fetch method? In the componentDidMount (if class component) or in the useEffect (if function component)

Comment: Iam soo sorry @PrathameshKoshti I am dealing with some confidential data. basically I'm intern at a company this api is not public I am not getting enough help from them. :( so I cant actually give the end point, as it might not work for u, as well....... I think there is something wrong with the response as well, its not actually what I have used in past :) thanks I will ask them about this

Comment: No problem, If you think its an issue with the API, you can use Postman tool to test if API is working properly or not. Or else console log the received data this way:
```fetch('http://someurl', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify({"Authentication":'someToken'})
      }).then(data => console.log(data.json()));
```

Comment: Please update your question to include a full [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example. We should be able to see what the initial state is, what is done to state over time, and how you are consuming your state object. The fetch request alone isn't enough to know what/why/how any errors are triggered. Based on your logs `this.state.items` is undefined, likely on the initial render before populated by the fetch.

Comment: @DrewReese okay sure sir I will update my question..

Answer (score 2):

Here, console.log(this.state.items[0]); is getting called two times; 
- When the page first loads and API request is not finished. 
- After the API request finishes and you call this.setState

Solution would be to check that items' length is greater than 0 before trying to use it. Try changing console.log(this.state.items[0]); to this:

`if (this.state.items.length > 0) { console.log(this.state.items[0].Status); }`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use componentWillMount() instead of componentDidMount() becuase componentWillMount() happens before render while componentDidMount() happens after the first render.May be that help.